# Django: django.contrib.sites, SITE_ID, breaks app

Tags: django

I just delayed my first Django app via Heroku and I'm having an issue that's proving very difficult to resolve. I have django-registration and profiles installed and apparently something runs afoul unless the 'django.contrib.sites', and SITE_ID is removed from settings. Unfortunately, when content is submitted by a user to be displayed, I'm getting the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'SITE_ID'.
```

Only when deleting the user submitted content via the admin does the site reestore.

Adding django.contrib.sites and SITE_ID back just kills the whole app. These issues did not arise during initial development, but only began when the app was deployed. Looking to see if anyone has any insight or advice on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of error do you get when you add SITE_ID in the settings file?

This problem usually occurs when there is a discrepancy with data in the table `django_site`. Check if your dev and prod database have the same values in that table. Some models may refer to some Django models that use the Site models itself, and unless they cannot find a valid `django.contrib.sites.models.site` instance in the database, they will raise an exception. This happens if using the FlatPage models for instance.

Comment: The first error when I switched the DB was "Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist." The others were similar. For instance, when trying to access comments in the admin, this occurs: "DatabaseError at /admin/comments/comment/
relation "django_site" does not exist" Not sure what happened during the transition nor the best way to repair it.

Comment: `relation "django_site" does not exist` - Did you run syncdb on the server ? It seems it didn't create some tables.

Comment: Should I run with or without django.contrib.sites and SITE_ID commented out?

Comment: Do not comment these, you probably need the SITE_ID.

Comment: Yes. Without it, I get this error: TemplateSyntaxError at /report/all/
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'SITE_ID'

Comment: That worked! One question: the site is now "example.com" instead of the correct domain name. Any way to change that without screwing it up again?

Comment: This only matters if you use the `site.domain` property from the Site model. It will obviously return `example.com`. If you don't use this property - then no problem.

Comment: I'm using it to send emails for registration, so the name does need to change.